# Пароль в cookies

Tags: пароль, php, cookie, безопасность

Безопасно ли хранить пароль в cookies не зашифрованным? 
То есть в куках он будет простым, типо 123456 , а в базе данных хранится в md5. Потом уже сверять.

Может ли злоумышленник как-то вытащить пароль из кук?

Comment: Друг сядет за комп - правой мыши и посмотрит очень быстро. Правда сохранённые пароли в ФФ таким способом легко смотрятся, но тут без сохранений всяких. Поэтому так делать не очень круто.

Comment: @Kremchik , плохой друг однако. ;)
Вопрос закройте пожалуйста. Ответ был дан. Спасибо большое

Comment: Ну я неправильно выразился, недруг скорее)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, может, поскольку `cookie` кэшируются, то их можно посмотреть в любой момент и для любого популярного браузера.